# How can authorized a user using refresh token in Google-drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i have both refresh token and access token in my Google-drive API. but i don't want to request a new access token each time when user use my API for that i store my refresh token.
how can i get new access token from refresh token

Comment: You posted this question twice, please delete this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate an access token from a refresh token for the Google Drive API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983626/how-do-i-generate-an-access-token-from-a-refresh-token-for-the-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one

```
   authCode = "Your Refresh Code";
    IAuthorizationState = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
```