# How do I generate an access token from a refresh token for the Google Drive API?

Tags: oauth, authorization, google-drive-api

I have both access token and refresh token. But the access token expires after few time so i want to generate access token from refresh token for Google drive API. so give me idea or code to generate access token from refresh token for Google drive API.

Answer (score 1):

The Drive SDK client libraries all perform refresh automatically, so you don't need to worry about it mostly.

If you are performing auth manually (not advised) you can check the documentation for [OAuth 2.0 offline access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline). You can also test it with the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&apisSelect=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&url=https://&content_type=application/json&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=unchecked&oauthEndpointSelect=Google&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&includeCredentials=unchecked&accessTokenType=oauth&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&forceAprovalPrompt=checked&response_type=code).